# No available connection after switching to KDE from GNOME

Tags: network-manager, kde

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I decided to switch from GNOME to KDE Plasma as windows manager.

The issue is that i cannot see any connection in connection manager (try icon and under system setting all is empty) but i can use wired connection without any issue. If i Switch back to GNOME (i did not uninstalled) i can see all my connections.

Is this a know issue, or does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please be clear with details; GNOME is a desktop that uses the `mutter` window manager, KDE Plasma is likewise a desktop but uses the `kwin` window manager by default, you mention changing window managers; yet mention only the desktops? Was it the desktop you changed (including WM)? or please be clear? (WM and desktops are different things & it maybe it was only desktop you meant). Possibly giving details of what change(s) you made, such as what you installed, will help. Is your KDE Plasma system complete? or have you changed default WM's of the desktops you mention.